# Is it correct to set base href to /

Tags: html

I'm updating a site to use HTML5 history for bookmarking/link sharing etc.

The URLs will be this shape. http://weathersupermarket.co.uk/forecasts/1,10,4,3,7

All requests were previously served from http://weathersupermarket.co.uk/ and all my references were relative, e.g. img/loading.gif, js/main.min.js etc.

Therefore I'll need to update all my CSS, JS, image references to be either

- relative e.g. ../img/loading.gif
- absolute e.g. /img/loading.gif

However I've found that if I set the base tag to /, i.e. the absolute root then I can leave my references as relative, e.g. img/loading.gif

Is this correct?

```
<base href="/" />
```

I've found lots of similar questions on the base tag, but nothing that covers this specific case.

The [W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/base.html) states that href attribute is simply a URL. The [RFC for URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987) appears to allow /.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<base href="/">` is completely valid in HTML5. According to [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-base-element), the base URL is determined basing on the fallback base URL (for example, on `http://example.com/base/com/a`, it's `http://example.com/base/com`).

Because of that `/` will always refer to the actual base of website.